# In WPF, can you bind a ListView (NOT DataGrid) to a Matrix (Cross-Tab) DataSet?

Tags: wpf, listview, reporting, crosstab

Is it possible in WPF to bind a ListView (NOT a DataGrid) to a Matrix (Cross-Tab) DataSet in which the columns are unknown beforehand?

Using the Northwind database as an example: the simple query below will return a wellknown dataset which can easily be bound to a listview:

```
SELECT  Year(o.OrderDate) AS [Year], Month(o.OrderDate) AS [Month], 
COUNT(o.OrderID) AS [NumOrders]
FROM Orders o 
GROUP BY Year(o.OrderDate), Month(o.OrderDate)
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

[image]

To generate a more meaningful report, we might run the result set from the above query (in a reporting program) to generate some thing as below shown below:

```
SELECT  [Year], 
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 1 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 2 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 3 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mar',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 4 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Apr',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 5 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 6 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 7 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 8 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 9 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 10 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 11 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov',
SUM(CASE [Month] WHEN 12 Then NumOrders ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec'
FROM
( 
SELECT  Year(o.OrderDate) AS [Year], Month(o.OrderDate) AS [Month], 
COUNT(o.OrderID) AS [NumOrders]
FROM Orders o 
GROUP BY Year(o.OrderDate), Month(o.OrderDate)
)t0
GROUP BY [Year]
```

Which results into something like this:

[image]

My question is, It it possible to bind this final result to a ListView or a Flowdocument in WPF without having prior knowledge of the resulting columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add columns dynamically to a ListView by using Attached Properties. Check out this article on the **CodeProject** it explains exactly that...

[WPF DynamicListView - Binding to a DataMatrix](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DynamicListView.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the GridViewColumns for the ListView programatically and apply the binding to that. Loop through the columns in the DataSet and add a corresponding GridViewColumn into the ListView.

```
var gridView = (GridView)list.View;
foreach(var col in table.Columns) {
   gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn{
      Header=col.ColumnName, 
      DisplayMemberBinding=new Binding(col.ColumnName)});
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this result using the M-V-VM design pattern?